# Special implementation of class methods depending on constructor parameters

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class:

```
    class MyClass {
      int param_;
      void MyMethod();
     public:
      MyClass(int param) : param_(param) {};
    }

    void MyClass::MyMethod() {
      if (param_ == 1) {
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
        /* */
      } else {
        std::cout << "not 1" << std::endl;
        /* */
      }
    }
```

I want to depose of that "if" statements with another class `MyClass1` having the same definition but different implementation.

I don't want users carrying about this difference. Is it possible to initialize objects of different classes in the same way?

```
MyClass a(5);
MyClass b(1);
a.MyMethod(); // not 1
b.MyMethod(); // 1
```

I don't want to use `if` because there could be many such methods having different implementations.

Comment: How would you like to differentiate between the outputs then? if a single function can take multiple execution paths, you basically have to use a branching statement, such as `if`.

Comment: @Amit I want to use "if" statement once instead of repeating it in each method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds as a job for inheritance and a factory method

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void MyMethod() = 0;
}

class Class1: public Base
{
    public:
    virtual void MyMethod(){// implement 1}
}
class ClassNot1: public Base // or public Class1, if you have some implementation in Class1 you want use in this class
{
    public:
    virtual void MyMethod(){// implement not 1}
}

Base* SomeFactoryClass::GetBase(int param)
{
    if (param == 1)
        return new Class1();
    else
        return new ClassNot1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance by the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    virtual void MyMethod(void)
    {
        cout << "1" << endl;
    }
};

class MyClass1 : public MyClass
{
public:
    virtual void MyMethod(void) override
    {
        cout << "not 1" << endl;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass* a = new MyClass();
MyClass* b = new MyClass1();
a->MyMethod();               // prints 1
b->MyMethod();               // prints not 1
```

Some info about inheritance in c++: [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w5c4hyx3.aspx), [two](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ck561bfk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @alexeykusmin0 I wanted a and b objects initialized in the same way. User may not know if there is different implementations and another class MyClass1, he knows only MyClass

Comment: @user162065 then you probably should use factory method as mentioned in Gian Paolo's answer